# Clash between anchor tag right click and listgrid set context menu

Tags: gwt, contextmenu, anchor, smartgwt, listgrid

I have to display document name as a link in a column of listgrid (smartgwt). We already have caught right click handler on the grid and show our own customized context menu which works fine. Now due to a requirement the document names appear as hyperlink(anchor tag) on click of which the document opens. but now when user clicks on the hyperlink, the normal menu with open, open in new tab appears (which I dont want to) at the first time.

Clicking elsewhere and then right clicking on hyperlink shows our own customized menu (which I want everytime to come) but it doesn't work. But the same menu works fine when right clicked on some other part of the listgrid. I tried many things but it didn't work correctly. Kindly help. JSNI is also feasible.

Comment: Can you post a standalone code so that I can also reproduce the issue? If possible, post some snapshots representing the issue, too.

Comment: @RAS, sorry got busy in the work so couldn't open SO. I solved the problem by calling a JSNI method and customizing it when right click on anchor tag is done. Cheers!

Comment: You don't need to be. It's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by capturing the right click and customizing it according to my needs using JSNI.